# OCaml: Type error while combining recursive modules and private type abbreviations

Tags: ocaml

I am currently working with OCaml, and I want to create some types which are somehow secured, in the sense that I want to select only those instances which satisly some properties.

The way that I found to acheive that is to encapsulate my type in a module, making it private, and defining the constructors in such a way that they check if the object that they are trying to make satisfy these properties. As my code is a bit long, I want to split into different modules, but my types are mutually recursive, so I am using recursive modules. I end up in the following situation (I simplified a lot so that it becomes readable)

```
module rec A
: sig
  type t = private int list
  val secured_cons : int -> t -> t                          
end
= struct
  type t = int list

  let cons (i:int) (x:t) : t = i::x

  let secured_cons i x : t = B.checker i x; cons i x
end

and B
: sig
  val checker : int -> A.t -> unit
end
= struct
  let checker i x = ()
end
```

But this code is rejected, with the following error message :

```
Characters 226-227:
let secured_cons i x = B.checker i x; cons i x
                                             ^
Error: This expression has type A.t but an expression was expected of type
     t = int list
```

This looks to me very weird, because as we are in the context `A`, the two types `t` and `A.t` are supposed to be equal. From my understanding, what happens is that inside `A`, the type t is considered to be a synonym for `int list` whereas outside `A`, the signature tells us that it is private, so it is just a copy of this type, with a coercion `A.t :> int list`. The entire point is that there is no coercion the other way around, which is exactly why I want to use private type abbreviations

But in my case I am inside the module `A`, so I would like to use this extra information to say that my type `t` should coerce to `A.t`

Does anyone have a better explanation of why this error is happening, and how I could avoid it? (I have thought of switching to abstract types, but I get exactly the same error)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to solve this issue I am posting it here in case anyone else ever encounters the same.

We just have to explicitly specify what types and coercion we expect from the system - here is my example slightly modified in a correct way :

```
module rec A
: sig
  type t = private int list
  val secured_cons : int -> t -> t                          
end
= struct
  type t = int list

  let cons (i:int) (x:t) : t = i::x

  let secured_cons i (x:A.t) = B.checker i x; cons i (x :> t)
end

and B
: sig
  val checker : int -> A.t -> unit
end
= struct
  let checker i x = ()
end
```

It might look silly to write `let secured_cons i (x:A.t)` inside the module `A` itself, but as far as I understand it, it is the only way to specify to the system that it should go out of the module to check the signature, and use the same type as the signature (so here a private type) instead of the internal type `t` which is still a synonymous for `int list`

I had more trickier cases, but this idea could be adapted to each of them, and helped me solve them all.

Still I am not entirely sure of what is happening, and if anyone has clearer explanations, I would be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

You're errors occur because when `B.checker` is invoked, **x** is infered as an **A.t** because of the signature of **B**. 
You can see that easily if you explicitly type the **secured_cons** function :

```
let secured_cons i (x:t) : t = B.checker i x; cons i x
```

which now produces the symmetrical error:

```
let secured_cons i (x:t) = B.checker i x; cons i x
                                       ^
Error: This expression has type t = int list                                           
but an expression was expected of type A.t
```

In fact you here have a real designing problem in my opinion. If you want the module **B** to check the values produced by the module **A**, so without surprise B must inspect in some way the type **A.t**. Having that type **private** makes it impossible.

From what i understand you have three options :

1. remove **private**
2. Add a browse, getter function that allows the B module to access the content of the values of type **A.t**
3. the way i would do this : put the checking function into the module **A**

Comment: Thanks, as I answered to @RichouHunter, the optimal way consisting in putting the checker inside the module `A` is not applicable in my real case, but it is true that it is the thing to do in my example. I gave a way to solve this problem, by explicitly typing the function in another way that the one you proposed

Answer (score 0):

I'd be glad to hear what more experienced users have to say about this, but here is my take on it.

I, as a developer, usually give a lot of importance to the semantics of a code. In your case, the `B` module is specifically used by the `A` module, and it has no other goal than that.

Thus, sticking to a nested module (even if it makes your code a bit longer) would be the way to go as far as I am concerned. There is no point is exposing the `B` module. Below is the refactored example to illustrate.

```
module A : sig
  type t
  val secured_cons : int -> t -> t
end = struct
  type t = int list

  module B : sig
    val checker : int -> t -> unit
  end = struct
    let checker i x = ()
  end

  let cons i x = i::x

  let secured_cons i x = B.checker i x; cons i x
end
```

And here is the signature of the module as given by `utop`:

```
module A : sig type t val secured_cons : int -> t -> t end
```

which is perfect in my sense because it only shows the interface to your module, and nothing of its implementation.

---

As a side-note, if you wanted to expose the signature of the `B` module (to give it to a functor, for example), just move it to the signature of the `A` module, as follows:

```
module A : sig
  type t
  val secured_cons : int -> t -> t
  module B : sig
    val checker : int -> t -> unit
  end
end = struct
  type t = int list

  module B = struct
    let checker i x = ()
  end

  let cons i x = i::x

  let secured_cons i x = B.checker i x; cons i x
end;;
```

Here is the signature of the module as given by `utop`:

```
module A :
  sig
    type t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    val secured_cons : int -> t -> t                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    module B : sig val checker : int -> t -> unit end                                                                                                                                                                                          
  end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer, I don't think what you propose here is much possible, because in my real case I have many `A` modules, that are recursively dependent on each others, and one single `B` module that checks the correctedness of all constructions in the `A` modules. The problem that I encountered in my initial post was not only in one of the `A` but in many of them, and as a result, if I tried to nest `B` in one of the `A`, I would still encounter the same problems in the others `A`. Still I get the idea, and I think it is the right thing to do in simpler cases

Comment: I see. Maybe you want to look into functors to inject the `B` module into whatever module fits a given signature.

Comment: I thought of that too, but the signature of `B` itself depends on the various modules `A`, so I don't see how I can define the signature `B` without using recursive modules

Answer (score 0):

> Still I am not entirely sure of what is happening, and if anyone has clearer explanations, I would be very thankful

A private type abbreviation of the form `type u = private t` *declares* a type `u` that is *distinct* from the implementation type `t`. It is the same as declaring an abstract type with the following two exceptions:

1. compiler treats the type `t`, as an implementation type, that opens an avenue for optimizations - this, however, doesn't mean that a type checker considers them the same, for the type checker they are *distinct*.
2. typechecker allows a coercion of type `u` to type `t`.

So, from a typechecker perspective, these two types are distinct. As always in OCaml type discipline all coercions should be made explicit, and a subtype is not equal to a super type unless it is coerced. In your case, the typechecker is trying to unify type `A.t = private int list` with type `int list` since `A.t` and `int list` are distinct types, it is rejected. It is, however, allowed to coerce `A.t` to `int list` (but not the vice verse).

> It might look silly to write let secured_cons i (x:A.t) inside the module A itself

You don't need to write it (at least in your simple example). Just using `x :> t` is enough.